# where to find rocprofiler derived counters description with examples

Tags: c, opencl, amd-rocm

My opencl kernel taking too long to finish, `rocprof` gave me below counters:

```
| Index | KernelName    | gpu-id | queue-id | queue-index |    pid |    tid |  grd | wgr |  lds | scr | arch_vgpr | accum_vgpr | sgpr | wave_size |            sig |            obj |   TCC_RW_REQ_sum | TCC_PROBE_sum | TCC_PROBE_ALL_sum |     TCC_READ_sum | TA_DATA_STALLED_BY_TC_CYCLES_sum | TA_FLAT_WAVEFRONTS_sum | TD_SPI_STALL_sum | TCP_TOTAL_ATOMIC_WITH_RET_sum | TCP_TOTAL_ATOMIC_WITHOUT_RET_sum | TCP_TOTAL_WRITEBACK_INVALIDATES_sum | TCP_UTCL1_REQUEST_sum |  TCC_WRITE_sum | TCC_ATOMIC_sum |      TCC_HIT_sum |    TCC_MISS_sum |    L2CacheHit | TA_FLAT_ATOMIC_WAVEFRONTS_sum | TA_BUFFER_WAVEFRONTS_sum | TCP_UTCL1_TRANSLATION_MISS_sum | TCP_UTCL1_TRANSLATION_HIT_sum | TCP_UTCL1_PERMISSION_MISS_sum | TCP_TOTAL_CACHE_ACCESSES_sum | TCC_WRITEBACK_sum | TCC_EA_WR_UNCACHED_32B_sum | TCC_EA_WRREQ_IO_CREDIT_STALL_sum | TCC_EA_WRREQ_GMI_CREDIT_STALL_sum | TA_BUFFER_READ_WAVEFRONTS_sum | TA_BUFFER_WRITE_WAVEFRONTS_sum | TCP_TCP_LATENCY_sum | TCP_TA_TCP_STATE_READ_sum | TCP_TCC_READ_REQ_LATENCY_sum | TCP_TCC_WRITE_REQ_LATENCY_sum |     FETCH_SIZE |   WRITE_SIZE |  WRITE_REQ_32B |      FetchSize |    WriteSize |   MemWrites32B | TCC_EA_WRREQ_sum | TCC_EA_WRREQ_64B_sum | TCC_EA_RDREQ_sum | TCC_EA_RDREQ_32B_sum |  VFetchInsts |  VWriteInsts | MemUnitStalled | TA_FLAT_READ_WAVEFRONTS_sum | TA_FLAT_WRITE_WAVEFRONTS_sum |    TD_TD_BUSY_sum |   TD_TC_STALL_sum |     TCP_GATE_EN1_sum |  TCP_GATE_EN2_sum | TCP_TD_TCP_STALL_CYCLES_sum |       TCA_CYCLE_sum |       TCA_BUSY_sum | FlatVMemInsts |         LDSInsts | ALUStalledByLDS |        GPUBusy |        VALUInsts | FlatLDSInsts |     Wavefronts | TCC_EA_WRREQ_DRAM_CREDIT_STALL_sum | TCC_TOO_MANY_EA_WRREQS_STALL_sum | TCC_EA_WRREQ_LEVEL_sum | TCC_EA_RDREQ_LEVEL_sum | TA_BUFFER_ATOMIC_WAVEFRONTS_sum | TA_BUFFER_TOTAL_CYCLES_sum | TCP_TCC_READ_REQ_sum | TCP_TCC_WRITE_REQ_sum | TCP_TCC_ATOMIC_WITH_RET_REQ_sum | TCP_TCC_ATOMIC_WITHOUT_RET_REQ_sum | TCC_EA_ATOMIC_sum | TCC_EA_ATOMIC_LEVEL_sum | TCC_EA_RD_UNCACHED_32B_sum | TCC_EA_RDREQ_IO_CREDIT_STALL_sum | TA_BUFFER_COALESCED_READ_CYCLES_sum | TA_BUFFER_COALESCED_WRITE_CYCLES_sum | TCP_TCC_NC_READ_REQ_sum | TCP_TCC_NC_WRITE_REQ_sum | TCP_TCC_NC_ATOMIC_REQ_sum | TCP_TCC_UC_READ_REQ_sum | TCC_EA_RDREQ_GMI_CREDIT_STALL_sum | TCC_EA_RDREQ_DRAM_CREDIT_STALL_sum | TCC_TAG_STALL_sum | TCC_NORMAL_WRITEBACK_sum | TCP_TCC_UC_WRITE_REQ_sum | TCP_TCC_UC_ATOMIC_REQ_sum | TCP_TCC_CC_READ_REQ_sum | TCP_TCC_CC_WRITE_REQ_sum | TCC_ALL_TC_OP_WB_WRITEBACK_sum | TCC_NORMAL_EVICT_sum | TCC_ALL_TC_OP_INV_EVICT_sum | TCC_EA_RDREQ_DRAM_sum | TCP_TCC_CC_ATOMIC_REQ_sum | TCP_TCC_RW_READ_REQ_sum | TCP_TCC_RW_WRITE_REQ_sum | TCP_TCC_RW_ATOMIC_REQ_sum | TCC_EA_WRREQ_DRAM_sum | TCP_PENDING_STALL_CYCLES_sum | WriteUnitStalled |     TCC_BUSY_avr | TCC_WRREQ_STALL_max |        TCC_CYCLE_sum |      TCC_BUSY_sum |      TCC_REQ_sum | TCC_EA_WRREQ_STALL_sum |  MemUnitBusy |     TA_BUSY_avr |      TA_BUSY_max |  TA_BUSY_min |    TA_TA_BUSY_sum | TA_TOTAL_WAVEFRONTS_sum | TD_LOAD_WAVEFRONT_sum | TD_ATOMIC_WAVEFRONT_sum | TCP_TCR_TCP_STALL_CYCLES_sum | TCP_READ_TAGCONFLICT_STALL_CYCLES_sum | TCP_WRITE_TAGCONFLICT_STALL_CYCLES_sum | TCP_ATOMIC_TAGCONFLICT_STALL_CYCLES_sum |        SALUInsts |   SFetchInsts |     GDSInsts | VALUUtilization |     VALUBusy |     SALUBusy | LDSBankConflict | TCC_STREAMING_REQ_sum | TCC_NC_REQ_sum | TCC_UC_REQ_sum | TCC_CC_REQ_sum | TA_ADDR_STALLED_BY_TC_CYCLES_sum | TA_ADDR_STALLED_BY_TD_CYCLES_sum | TD_STORE_WAVEFRONT_sum | TD_COALESCABLE_WAVEFRONT_sum |  TCP_VOLATILE_sum | TCP_TOTAL_ACCESSES_sum | TCP_TOTAL_READ_sum | TCP_TOTAL_WRITE_sum |       DispatchNs |          BeginNs |            EndNs |       CompleteNs |
|     0 | kernel1.kd    |      0 |        0 |           0 | 352005 | 352009 | 6400 |  64 | 1024 |   0 |        48 |          0 |   32 |        64 | 0x7f4d1388e100 | 0x7f4c11844a00 | 25728.0000000000 |  0.0000000000 |      0.0000000000 | 25606.0000000000 |                 12327.0000000000 |        1800.0000000000 |     0.0000000000 |                  0.0000000000 |                     0.0000000000 |                      100.0000000000 |       2100.0000000000 | 300.0000000000 |   0.0000000000 | 25437.0000000000 |  467.0000000000 | 98.0813814054 |                  0.0000000000 |             0.0000000000 |                 100.0000000000 |               1700.0000000000 |                100.0000000000 |              2100.0000000000 |     64.0000000000 |               0.0000000000 |                     0.0000000000 |                      0.0000000000 |                  0.0000000000 |                   0.0000000000 |   456014.0000000000 |           1800.0000000000 |            185980.0000000000 |              56218.0000000000 |  49.9375000000 | 3.9062500000 | 125.0000000000 |  49.9375000000 | 3.9062500000 | 125.0000000000 |    63.0000000000 |        62.0000000000 |   799.0000000000 |         0.0000000000 | 0.0000000000 | 0.0000000000 |   0.0224162944 |             1500.0000000000 |               300.0000000000 | 323668.0000000000 | 281804.0000000000 |  66528293.0000000000 | 403183.0000000000 |                0.0000000000 |  2580712.0000000000 |  424928.0000000000 | 18.0000000000 |  2021.0000000000 |    0.0000000000 | 100.0000000000 | 10410.0000000000 | 0.0000000000 | 100.0000000000 |                       0.0000000000 |                     0.0000000000 |        3720.0000000000 |       92654.0000000000 |                    0.0000000000 |               0.0000000000 |      1152.0000000000 |        300.0000000000 |                    0.0000000000 |                       0.0000000000 |      0.0000000000 |            0.0000000000 |             130.0000000000 |                     0.0000000000 |                        0.0000000000 |                         0.0000000000 |            0.0000000000 |             0.0000000000 |              0.0000000000 |            0.0000000000 |                      0.0000000000 |                       0.0000000000 |   2872.0000000000 |             0.0000000000 |             0.0000000000 |              0.0000000000 |            0.0000000000 |             0.0000000000 |                  32.0000000000 |         0.0000000000 |                0.0000000000 |        741.0000000000 |              0.0000000000 |         1152.0000000000 |           300.0000000000 |              0.0000000000 |         63.0000000000 |            216083.0000000000 |     0.0000000000 |  9780.5625000000 |        0.0000000000 |  21183648.0000000000 | 312978.0000000000 | 25466.0000000000 |           0.0000000000 | 0.1040613968 | 4230.6875000000 |  5511.0000000000 | 0.0000000000 |  67691.0000000000 |         1800.0000000000 |       1800.0000000000 |            0.0000000000 |                 0.0000000000 |                          0.0000000000 |                           0.0000000000 |                            0.0000000000 |  4344.0000000000 |  9.0000000000 | 0.0000000000 |   12.8938886488 | 1.5124873676 | 0.6309656319 |    0.0000000000 |          0.0000000000 | 112.0000000000 |  65.0000000000 |   0.0000000000 |                     0.0000000000 |                     0.0000000000 |         300.0000000000 |              1200.0000000000 |  57600.0000000000 |       57600.0000000000 |   48000.0000000000 |     9600.0000000000 | 3664882497116233 | 3664135843101786 | 3664882514625889 | 3664882514742848 |
|     1 | kernel2.kd    |      0 |        0 |           2 | 352005 | 352009 | 6400 |  64 | 1024 |  16 |        72 |          0 |   96 |        64 | 0x7f4d1388e200 | 0x7f4c11844a40 | 58756.0000000000 |  0.0000000000 |      0.0000000000 | 58351.0000000000 |                 12361.0000000000 |        3800.0000000000 |     0.0000000000 |                  0.0000000000 |                     0.0000000000 |                      100.0000000000 |       4900.0000000000 | 700.0000000000 |   0.0000000000 | 56967.0000000000 | 1088.0000000000 | 98.0573111175 |                  0.0000000000 |           200.0000000000 |                 200.0000000000 |               3700.0000000000 |                200.0000000000 |              4900.0000000000 |     30.0000000000 |               0.0000000000 |                     0.0000000000 |                      0.0000000000 |                100.0000000000 |                 100.0000000000 |   878610.0000000000 |           4000.0000000000 |            397328.0000000000 |             129527.0000000000 | 101.3125000000 | 0.0000000000 |   0.0000000000 | 101.3125000000 | 0.0000000000 |   0.0000000000 |     0.0000000000 |         0.0000000000 |  1621.0000000000 |         0.0000000000 | 1.0000000000 | 1.0000000000 |   0.0108338625 |             3500.0000000000 |               300.0000000000 | 729388.0000000000 | 634273.0000000000 | 557707761.0000000000 | 905423.0000000000 |                0.0000000000 | 23601924.0000000000 | 1053565.0000000000 | 38.0000000000 | 17652.8800000000 |    0.0000000000 | 100.0000000000 | 86416.8800000000 | 0.0000000000 | 100.0000000000 |                       0.0000000000 |                     0.0000000000 |           0.0000000000 |      163630.0000000000 |                    0.0000000000 |             800.0000000000 |      2630.0000000000 |        700.0000000000 |                    0.0000000000 |                       0.0000000000 |      0.0000000000 |            0.0000000000 |             144.0000000000 |                     0.0000000000 |                      400.0000000000 |                       400.0000000000 |            0.0000000000 |             0.0000000000 |              0.0000000000 |            0.0000000000 |                      0.0000000000 |                       0.0000000000 |   2588.0000000000 |             0.0000000000 |             0.0000000000 |              0.0000000000 |            0.0000000000 |             0.0000000000 |                   0.0000000000 |         0.0000000000 |                0.0000000000 |       1558.0000000000 |              0.0000000000 |         2630.0000000000 |           700.0000000000 |              0.0000000000 |          0.0000000000 |            434042.0000000000 |     0.0000000000 | 23384.9375000000 |        0.0000000000 | 188428736.0000000000 | 748318.0000000000 | 59052.0000000000 |           0.0000000000 | 0.0227353858 | 8258.3125000000 | 10710.0000000000 | 0.0000000000 | 132133.0000000000 |         4000.0000000000 |       4000.0000000000 |            0.0000000000 |                 0.0000000000 |                          0.0000000000 |                           0.0000000000 |                            0.0000000000 | 46104.9200000000 | 18.0000000000 | 0.0000000000 |   17.3315676902 | 1.4111824381 | 0.7528644267 |    0.0000000000 |          0.0000000000 | 224.0000000000 |  75.0000000000 |   0.0000000000 |                     0.0000000000 |                     0.0000000000 |         400.0000000000 |              2700.0000000000 | 126400.0000000000 |      126400.0000000000 |  115200.0000000000 |    11200.0000000000 | 3664882525999037 | 3664882529819153 | 3664882563472360 | 3664882563585605 |
```

I tried to understand the columns with `rocprof --list-derived` but its description to counters is very short n I couldn't comprehend much. For example, it says

```
TA_BUSY_avr : TA block is busy. Average over TA instances.
      TA_BUSY_avr = avr(TA_TA_BUSY,16)
```

What's a TA block? and:

```
TD_TD_BUSY_sum : TD is processing or waiting for data. Perf_Windowing not supported for this counter. Sum over TD instances.
      TD_TD_BUSY_sum = sum(TD_TD_BUSY,16)
```

What's a TD instance? and:

```
TCP_GATE_EN1_sum : TCP interface clocks are turned on. Not Windowed. Sum over TCP instances.
      TCP_GATE_EN1_sum = sum(TCP_GATE_EN1,16)
```

What's a TCP instance? and:

```
TCA_CYCLE_sum : Number of cycles. Sum over all TCA instances
      TCA_CYCLE_sum = sum(TCA_CYCLE,16)
```

What's a TCA instance? and:

```
TCC_WRREQ_STALL_max : Number of cycles a write request was stalled. Max over TCC instances.
      TCC_WRREQ_STALL_max = max(TCC_EA_WRREQ_STALL,32)
```

What's a TCC?

How can i improve my kernels `kernel1` and `kernel2`?

Answer (score 1):

There is the documentation which you can find on the internet. (see, https://rocm.docs.amd.com/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/ page 332)

- SQ - Sequencer
- TA - Texture Addressing Unit
- TC - Texture Cache
- TCA - Texture Cache Arbiter
- TCC - Texture Cache per Channel, known as L2 Cache
- TCIU - Texture Cache Interface Unit, Command Processor (CP)’s interface to memory system
- TCP - Texture Cache per Pipe, known as vector L1 Cache
- TCR - Texture Cache Router
- TD - Texture Data Unit
- EA - Efficiency Arbiter

Comment: the link seems broken